# Capturing Dynamic User Input in Azure DevOps Pipeline: Discovered After a Specific Command

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm currently working on an Azure DevOps pipeline, and I'm faced with the challenge of capturing dynamic user input. Specifically, I need to collect user input after running a specific command during the pipeline execution. This input should be discovered dynamically based on the command's output and then used in subsequent steps.

Here's the scenario I'm dealing with:

In Step 1 of my pipeline, I run a command that generates dynamic output. This output contains information that I need to capture as user input.

After running this command, I want to present users with a text box or a form within the pipeline UI where they can input additional custom text data related to the dynamic output from Step 1.

This user input collected in Step 2 should then be passed as a parameter or variable to Step 3 for further processing.

I'm aware that Azure DevOps pipelines are primarily designed for automation and may not have built-in GUI elements for user input. However, I'm looking for a solution that allows me to integrate a user-friendly input mechanism into my pipeline after running a specific command in a dynamic manner.

Is there a recommended approach or any available tools or extensions that can help me achieve this workflow? I am specifically seeking a solution where users can provide input in a user-friendly and intuitive way in Step 2, based on dynamically discovered information from Step 1, and have that input seamlessly used in Step 3 of the pipeline.

Any guidance or examples of how to set this up would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Additional Information:

- I'm using Azure DevOps pipelines with YAML configurations.
- The input data provided by users in Step 2 will be used as parameters or variables in Step 3.
- I am open to external integrations or custom scripting solutions if they can help achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Step 2 you mentioned, it is involving manual interactive between users and the running pipeline. This typically needs a task which can run in Agentless jobs ([**Server jobs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#server-jobs)).

Currently, the built-in tasks supported in Agentless jobs are the following:
[image]

None of them is able to allow users to manual input some values and pass the values as parameter or variable to the subsequent steps/jobs/stages during the pipeline is running.

Have checked the marketplace of Azure DevOps, also did not find any extension provides the available Agentless job task.

So, your demand is not possible to meet currently.

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

Comment: Thanks for your research and the update. It seems like there is nothing to implement mentioned scenario it at this point.